# If I'm not Catholic, will a Catholic priest bless my home?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, blessings, ritual

If I'm a Protestant, and ask a Catholic priest to come bless my home, does the Catholic Church allow him to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The General Rules Concerning Blessings (*De benedictionibus regulæ generales*) in the [*Roman Ritual* (*Rituale Romanum* vol. 3: Blessings)](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7240) p. 3 says:

> 3. Blessings are designed primarily for Catholics, but may likewise be given to Catechumens. Moreover, unless the Church ex­pressly forbids, they may be imparted to non-Catholics to assist them in obtaining the light of faith, or together with it, bodily health.
>
> <sup>3. Benedictiones, imprimis impertiendæ catholicis, dari quo­que possunt catechumenis, immo, nisi obstet Ecclesiæ prohibi­tio, etiam acatholicis ad obtinendum fidei lumen vel, una cum illo, corporis sanitatem.</sup>

So it seems permissible for a Catholic priest to bless a non-Catholic's home.

Comment: Sweet, love you guys! You're always welcoming and nice.

Answer (score 4):

If one is not Catholic, can a Catholic priest bless their home?

Generally speaking there is no problem here. Unless the Church expressly forbids a particular blessing it quite permitted. Some priests might decline to do, but there is no problem with it, ecclesiastically speaking.

> 3. Blessings are designed primarily for Catholics, but may likewise be given to catechumens. Moreover, unless the Church expressly forbids, they may be imparted to non-Catholics to assist them in obtaining the light of faith, or together with it, bodily health. - [General Rules Concerning Blessings](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/resource/55892/general-rules-concerning-blessings)

St. Maximilian Kolbe would hand out blessed Miraculous Medals to non-Catholics and non-Christians alike and made many conversations that way.

Fr. Gabriele Amorth, the famous exorcist of Rome employed the prayers of exorcism from the ***Rituale Romanum*** over non-Catholics many times.

I could easily find other examples of non-Catholics receiving Catholic sacramentals in one form or another.